# C source files not allowed when not using cgo or SWIG

Tags: macos, go, cross-compiling

I am using Go 1.6 on OSX 10.11.4 and trying to cross compile my go program for windows and linux. I use a library (https://github.com/pebbe/zmq4) in my go program which is a Go binding for a C based implementation. I followed the instructions to cross compile for x86 windows as listed [here](http://dave.cheney.net/2015/08/22/cross-compilation-with-go-1-5) by issuing the following command:

```
env GOOS=windows GOARCH=386 go build -v znode.go
```

However the above command  gives me the following error

```
znode.go:15:2: C source files not allowed when not using cgo or SWIG: dummy.c
```

Is there a workaround for this? I saw other posts on stackoverflow which suggest moving to go1.5 but i am already on go1.6

Comment: Do you have a cross-compiling C toolchain? You have to explicitly enable CGO when cross-compiling.

Comment: @JimB I'm not sure how to do that. Do i just add CGO_ENABLED=1 in my env? (Reference:https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9530).

Answer (score 2):

FWIW after six years ... user720694's comment has the clue. If there are any .c or .cpp/cc/etc. files in the build directory, adding `CGO_ENABLED=0` before `go build` does the trick.